# What are the rules for when each user defined conversion method is called implicity?

Tags: c++

[A little context.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

> In the world of classes, implicit conversions can be controlled by
>   means of three member functions:
>
> ```
> Single-argument constructors: allow implicit conversion from a particular type to initialize an object.
> Assignment operator: allow implicit conversion from a particular type on assignments.
> Type-cast operator: allow implicit conversion to a particular type.
> ```

I want to know how these different implicit conversions interact with each other. When does one override the others? What are the rules?

Comment: You want to know about [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) (if you don't already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those, the assignment operator, does not implement a conversion. You simply modify the state of one type of object based on data from an object of another type.

> When does one override the others?

When one is a better match by overload resolution. For example, if the source object is non-const, and converting constructor has non-const argument, while conversion operator is const qualified, then the converting constructor is a better match because identity conversion ranks higher than const conversion.

If the different conversions are ambiguous i.e. neither is a better match for overload resolution, then the program is ill-formed. In general, there is no need to have conflicting conversions, and they should be avoided. Either use a converting constructor or a conversion operator; not both.

The rules of overload resolution are in the section [over.match] of the standard. It's quite a long section and I won't copy it here.